# How to serve non-aspx files from a custom ASP.Net server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a custom ASP.Net server in a WinForms application. The server was created using **CreateApplicationHost** and a simple **HttpWorkerRequest** implementation.

I find that the custom server only processes requests for aspx files. **If I try to access xml / txt / png files from the browser, it gives a "The resource cannot be found." error.**

My question is: what must be done to be able to serve such files?

Comment: Can you not detect that static content is requested and simply return the file directly?

Comment: Create a HTTP Handler to handle other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the **HttpWorkerRequest.SendResponseFromFile** method must be overridden to send the file via the response stream.